# Phonegap app does not perform ajax call

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I have Phonegap build app for android made with html + javascript (jquery). Yesterday it was working perfectly. Today ajax calls does't perform anymore. Sample code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: urlPrefix + "/xxxxx",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    jsonpCallback: "indexCallback"
                });
                alert('Ajax praejo');

            },2000);

        });


        function indexCallback(response) {
            alert('callback prasideda');
        }
```

Alert after ajax call is showing, but alert in `indexCallback` function not appearing. Ajax calls external back-end server. I have made loging of calls in back-end server, but no call appears. 
I have tried to make timeout before ajax is calling, but no result.
I white listed all possible domains in config.xml file:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
<access origin="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
</platform>

<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
```

Everything works fine when i load index.html (ajax calls to external back-end) file into desktop browser.
Any ideas ?

Comment: Well i`m uploading html/css/js files into phonegap build. When building app and running in android phone.

Comment: Remove quotes for jsonpCallback

Comment: it started to work without any changes ....

Comment: It seems to be Wifi problem. With mobile data everything works perfectly, but when on WIFI app does't work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similiar problem with my app on android devices. After days of research i found following [blog post](http://www.cio.com/article/3146715/security/chrome-bug-triggered-errors-on-websites-using-symantec-ssl-certificates.html). The certificate from our cert authority(top 4 ) was part of a bug in google webview. After updating the webview and chrome on the devices everything worked again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Test again with the deviceready listener.

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
        setTimeout(function(){

            $.ajax({
                url: urlPrefix + "/xxxxx",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonpCallback: "indexCallback"
            });
            alert('Ajax praejo');

        },2000);
}

function indexCallback(response) {
        alert('callback prasideda');
}
```

2. Check your contents meta data.

   <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">